# Having difficulty retrieving city and area names using Geopy (Google V3)

Tags: python, geocoding, geopy, geocoding-service

I am using Geopy to call different addresses, to see what cities and neighbourhoods they belong to.

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
import json

places = '1238 Davie St, Vancouver, BC'

geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key='')
location = geolocator.geocode(places, language='en')

c = location.raw['address_components']
print c

counties = [c['long_name'] for c in c if 'neighborhood' in c['types']]
localities = [c['long_name'] for c in c if 'locality' in c['types']]
print counties, localities
```

Its working for counties, but not localities (cities).

```
[{u'long_name': u'1238', u'types': [u'street_number'], u'short_name': u'1238'}, {u'long_name': u'Davie Street', u'types': [u'route'], u'short_name': u'Davie St'}, {u'long_name': u'Central Vancouver', u'types': [u'neighborhood', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Central Vancouver'}, {u'long_name': u'Vancouver', u'types': [u'locality', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Vancouver'}, {u'long_name': u'Greater Vancouver', u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_2', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Greater Vancouver'}, {u'long_name': u'British Columbia', u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_1', u'political'], u'short_name': u'BC'}, {u'long_name': u'Canada', u'types': [u'country', u'political'], u'short_name': u'CA'}, {u'long_name': u'V6E 1N3', u'types': [u'postal_code'], u'short_name': u'V6E 1N3'}]
[u'Central Vancouver']

---> 32 localities = [c['long_name'] for c in c if 'locality' in c['types']]
     33 print counties,     localities

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Not sure why I am getting that mistake. I also want to be able to pass a Pandas column instead of typing in a static address, is there a neat way of doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful with your variable names. You're dangerously re-defining the variable `c` within your list comprehensions.

Do this instead:

```python
counties = [x['long_name'] for x in c if 'neighborhood' in x['types']]
localities = [x['long_name'] for x in c if 'locality' in x['types']]
```

Better yet, use different names entirely so your code is easier to read and reason about.

```py
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

address = '1238 Davie St, Vancouver, BC'

geocoder = GoogleV3(api_key='xyzabc')

location = geocoder.geocode(address, language='en')

address_components = location.raw['address_components']

counties = [addr['long_name'] for addr in address_components if 'neighborhood' in addr['types']]
localities = [addr['long_name'] for addr in address_components if 'locality' in addr['types']]
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working now! if instead of a static address I had a pandas column with the address data['address_full'] and I wanted all the value to go through the geocoding and create new columns for counties and localities, how should the code look like? I have tried different ways, mostly with loops and can't seem to make it work

Comment: I recommend asking a new question, probably over on https://stackoverflow.com/. It would be the same as if you were creating any column with the values being determined by a function. So try: 1) create a new column; 2) populate it with a value (any value); 3) populate it with a value from an existing column; 4) populate it as a function using a value from an existing column (e.g. `a + 5`). Just keep breaking your problem into smaller and smaller pieces until you solve it.